# Implementing my own binary tree

Tags: c++, templates, tree, binary-tree

For homework, I have to implement a binary tree (without using the STL binary tree) container. I have all of the tree functions working except for one.

Link to my code:
https://github.com/matthamil/BinaryTree

In bt_class.h, I have my binary_tree template class with template implementations.

In bintree.h, I have my binary_tree_node class with template implementations.

In main.cpp, I have a bunch of tests to make sure the functions work.

My problem is here:

```
template <class Item>
Item binary_tree<Item>::retrieve( ) const
{
    return current_ptr->data();
}
```

I need the return type of this function to be the data type of whatever is stored within binary_tree_node. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

With the current implementation, it returns a pointer to the current node.

I should be able to write

```
cout << test->retrieve();
```

in main.cpp and the output would be whatever the current node's data is. However, since it's returning a pointer, I have to add an extra step:

```
*first = test->retrieve();
cout << first->data() << endl;
//"first"
```

Can anyone offer any help?

Comment: No one is going to look through your code on a link.  Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: If your tree has current node, you've committed a major design goof.

Comment: You made `Item` (the template parameter for `binary_tree`) be the node type, rather than the value type.  That is an unusual choice and maybe should be fixed.  If you don't fix that, your definition of retrieve could use the C++11 feature `auto` in order to deduce the value type, or more complicated template coding could make the value type explicit.

Comment: The use of `Item` in your tree class and node class with two different meanings of `Item` is confusing.  I didn't try building your code, but I wouldn't expect it to compile, since that retrieve function seems to be returning an `Item` in the node sense of that type but is declared as returning an `Item` in the tree sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here and add_left, add_right.

```
template <class Item>
void binary_tree<Item>::create_first_node(const Item& entry)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        root_ptr = new Item(entry);
        current_ptr = root_ptr;
        count++;
    } else {
        std::cout << "Can't create first node for tree that has a first node already." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

What happens here is that you are passing the pointer of a node and calling new. So basically you are doing is creating a binary_tree_node(&binary_tree_node).

```
binary_tree_node<string> *first = new binary_tree_node<string> ("first");
binary_tree_node<string> *second = new binary_tree_node<string> ("second");
binary_tree_node<string> *third = new binary_tree_node<string> ("third");

test->create_first_node(*first);
test->add_right(*second);
test->add_left(*third);
```

Therefore inside your binary_tree_node there is another binary_tree_node.
There are different ways to fix it. The best way to fix it is just to assign the pointer to current_ptr instead or simply implement a proper copy constructor in your binary_tree_node. However as the comments already explained it is a BAD design choice. The class binary_tree should generate the binary_tree_node classes internally without the user having to manually instantiate the classes and deal with those pointers.